# Define and review web workers

Tags: reactjs, web-worker

I am working on an API that first takes the list from the server and then I want to resend it to each of the requested list items, but it takes a long time to use a thread in JavaScript.
Can anyone help me to use how a function to create a for loop in which a Worker requests us?

Sample function written

```js
let DivideNum = 10;
let cuttedIds = [
    [{id: "shVwksbhj78qr_bsj", name: "React"}],
    [{id: "jhjked89djYTeik_h", name: "React Native"}],
    ...
];
let CDs = useSelector(mybooks);
let dis = useDispatch();

let setWorkers = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < DivideNum; i++) {
      let worker = new Worker("worker.js");
      console.log("cuttedId " + (i + 1));
      console.log(cuttedIds[i]);
      //console.log("start posting ids...");
      worker.postMessage(cuttedIds[i]);
      //console.log("posting ids successfully...");
      worker.onmessage = (e) => {
        console.log("start messaging to worker...");
        if (e && e.data) {
          console.log("start reciving data...");
          dis(updateBooks([...CDs, e.data]));
          console.log("reciving data successfully...");
        }
      };
      worker.terminate();
    }
```

Comment: It is so inefficient. You sholuld not try to do that

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV
So what should I do?

Comment: Send your object/array at once. Do the operations on the server then return necessary data

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV 
No, I'm going to send 10 more IDs to the worker so that requests can be made at the same time, not in a row